# Consuming custom FaultException types Containing Methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

On my WCF service I have a couple of custom fault types. An abstract type called BaseFault and two implementations of it called TypeOneFault and TypeTwoFault

I am throwing the exception on the service side like this

```
public string ThisMethodHasFault(string eType)
{
    if (eType.Contains("One"))
    {
        TypeOneFault one = new TypeOneFault("TypeOneFault thrown");
        throw new FaultException<TypeOneFault>(one, new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("Fault reason here")));
    }
    else
    {
        TypeTwoFault two = new TypeTwoFault("TypeTwoFault thrown");
        throw new FaultException<TypeTwoFault>(two, new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("Fault reason here")));
    }

    return "";
}
```

My Service interface is like this

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(TypeOneFault ))]
[FaultContract(typeof(TypeTwoFault ))]
string ThisMethodHasFault(string eType);
```

On the client side I have a test winform application where I catch it like this

```
   MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();

   try
    {
        client.ThisMethodHasFault(""); //get value from user

    }
    catch (FaultException<TypeOneFault>  ox)
    {
         TypeOneFault oneEx = ox.Detail;
         oneEx.{property} ...

    }   
    catch (FaultException<TypeTwoFault>  tx)
    {
         TypeTwoFault twoEx = tx.Detail;
         twoEx.{property} ...
    }
```

**Question:**

In the method above I am only getting the custom fault class's property but not the method I have defined within it. The method is defined as abstract in the base abstract class which I implement in the child classes, TypeOne and TypeTwo. Is there a way to get the method as well?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: Done. Added the second one here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914534/wcf-consuming-custom-faultexception-types

Answer (score 4):

Methods do not serialize. Only data.

Comment: Thanks John. Can anything be done regarding the second question I put up?

Comment: Yes. Ask a separate question. "One question per question"

Comment: Posted the second one here>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914534/wcf-consuming-custom-faultexception-types

Answer (score 0):

The serialization that is supported is for data only. In essence, any web service necessarily hides the implementation and provides you the service only. What is serialized is the data types to enable any client to interact effectively. There is no need for serializing the methods.