# Catching multiple custom FaultException types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

On my WCF service I have a couple of custom fault types. An abstract type called BaseFault and two implementations of it called TypeOneFault and TypeTwoFault

I am throwing the exception on the service side like this

```
public string ThisMethodHasFault(string eType)
{
    if (eType.Contains("One"))
    {
        TypeOneFault one = new TypeOneFault("TypeOneFault thrown");
        throw new FaultException<TypeOneFault>(one, new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("Fault reason here")));
    }
    else
    {
        TypeTwoFault two = new TypeTwoFault("TypeTwoFault thrown");
        throw new FaultException<TypeTwoFault>(two, new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("Fault reason here")));
    }

    return "";
}
```

My Service interface is like this

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(TypeOneFault ))]
[FaultContract(typeof(TypeTwoFault ))]
string ThisMethodHasFault(string eType);
```

On the client side I have a test winform application where I catch it like this

```
   MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();

   try
    {
        client.ThisMethodHasFault(""); //get value from user

    }
    catch (FaultException<TypeOneFault>  ox)
    {
         TypeOneFault oneEx = ox.Detail;
         oneEx.{property} ...

    }   
    catch (FaultException<TypeTwoFault>  tx)
    {
         TypeTwoFault twoEx = tx.Detail;
         twoEx.{property} ...
    }
```

**Question:**

I cant seem to be able to reduce the number of catch blocks by doing this instead

```
    catch (FaultException<BaseFault> fex)
    {
         BaseFault Ex = fex.Detail;
         twoEx.{property} ...
    }
```

It would have been nice to have one such block that could capture any exception that I throw on the server and through abstraction I get the right class's details. By doing the above I get an error. `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

*Is there something I need to change to make this work or do I have to be content with multiple catch blocks only?*

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FaultException<T>` inherits from `FaultException`, so you can catch the base type instead:

```
catch(FaultException ex) {
    if(ex is FaultException<TypeOneFault>) {
        var detail = ((FaultException<TypeOneFault>) ex).Detail;
        // process it
    } else if(ex is FaultException<TypeTwoFault>) {
        var detail = ((FaultException<TypeTwoFault>) ex).Detail;
        // process it
    } else {
        // unexpected error
        throw;
    }
}
```

Unlike the two separate catch blocks, this can be refactored:

```
    catch(FaultException ex) {
        if(!ProcessFault(ex)) {
            throw;
        }

bool ProcessFault(FaultException ex) {
    if(ex is FaultException<TypeOneFault>) {
        var detail = ((FaultException<TypeOneFault>) ex).Detail;
        // process it
        return true;
    } else if(ex is FaultException<TypeTwoFault>) {
        var detail = ((FaultException<TypeTwoFault>) ex).Detail;
        // process it
        return true;
    } else {
        // unexpected error
        return false;
    }
}
```

If your two fault classes are not related, then that's as far as you can go. However, if they inherit from a common base, then you can refactor further:

```
bool ProcessFault(FaultException ex) {
    if(ex is FaultException<TypeOneFault>) {
        ProcessFault(((FaultException<TypeOneFault>) ex).Detail);
        return true;
    } else if(ex is FaultException<TypeTwoFault>) {
        ProcessFault(((FaultException<TypeTwoFault>) ex).Detail);
        return true;
    } else {
        // unexpected error
        return false;
    }
}

void ProcessFault(BaseFault detail) {
    // process it
}
```

Comment: Thats the same as having multiple catch blocks. I have to evaluate each exception separately..

Comment: It's just as many lines of code, but one catch block is a heck of a lot easier to deal with than two. You can refactor the contents into a separate method for a start.

Comment: Updated answer with what I think you want.

Comment: Thanks Christian, but wouldn't I be breaking the Open Close principle here? If another exception type is added then I need to revisit this method and add another ELSE clause. If I could just BaseClass b = new DerivedClass(); ....where I get the derived class somehow via the FaultException's variable ex then all I need to do is throw a new exception type in the service. The client doesnt need to change.

Comment: You are asking for behaviour that is simply not provided by the WCF API I'm afraid. The only solution is to code round it. I don't see how having to maintain one small method is breaking the OCP.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this, using [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) for convenience, but you could get the same effect using dynamic and some try/catch blocks:

```
try
{
    client.ThisMethodHasFault("");
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(e.GetType());
    var detail = accessor.GetMembers().Any(x => x.Name == "Detail")
                     ? accessor[e, "Detail"] as BaseFault
                     : null;

    if (detail != null)
    {
        // Do processing here
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```